# My headphone jack is messed up

Tags: imac

So I have a headset that i usually use for my iMac- Late 2015. and it worked perfectly. Then only one side works. i thought it was the headset, but I tried the headset on my phone and other 3 devices i have and the headset works perfectly on them, but not on my iMac.

Comment: Don't shoot me but you have checked the balance slider in the system prefs : sound ?

Comment: i feel like an idiot.. i dont know why that setting was messed with, but thanks man!